# How to install ICPC compiler on Ubuntu? Which package is it contained in?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, intel

I've got the Intel OneAPI repository in my apt and have tried to install a few of the packages but I cannot find the one that contains the icpc compiler.

`intel-oneapi-compiler-dpcpp-cpp` and `intel-oneapi-compiler-dpcpp-cpp-and-cpp-classic` did not have it.

Does someone know how I might be able to do this? I cannot find any decent / clear documentation. It all just says that this is in the HPC toolkit...

Installing the Intel toolkit is not the problem, I do not know which package within the toolkit I can install to actually use the compiler.

Installing the basekit is over 10 GB, I want only the compiler.

Comment: Would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19687111/how-to-install-a-simple-intel-c-c-compiler-on-a-64-bit-ubuntu-system

Comment: Unfortunately I could not glean what I need out of this. I have had no issuses getting the repository set up, I simply cannot find the exact package that contains the ICPC compiler in it. I feel like it should not be hard to find this information : (

Comment: I'm not a coder, but if I'm not badly mistaken, icpc compiler is Intel's c++ compiler. That one's part of oneAPI Toolkit. Download instructions are in https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/base-toolkit.html. If I _am_ mistaken, I very much appreciate if you correct me :-)

Comment: The basekit package is over 10 Gb and I only need the compiler out of it. I have that added as an apt repo and just want to find out the minimum packages I can install to have ICPC avaliable.

Answer (score 0):

`intel-oneapi-compiler-dpcpp-cpp-and-cpp-classic` does have it, in `/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/*/linux/bin/*`